# How can I deploy Azure Api App using msbuild

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-api-apps

I have created `Azure API App` and I am able to publish it using `Visual Studio 2015`.
Now I want to deploy it using `msbuild` within continuous deployment. 
I have tried this so far:

```
msbuild MyAzureApiApp.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=myPublishProfile.pubxml
```

But it is asking for `password`! I have checked the subscription `.publishsettings` file but can not find any password on it.

Note that I have also checked the hidden file `.pubxml.user` and found the password but it was encrypted?

So how can I get the password to deploy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the username and password are from Profile Publisher which can be downloaded from Azure Portal.